# Search Box(Filter) Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, search-box

[image]

I want to create search box as bellow image.

Comment: So what problem you are facing to do so?

Comment: Please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in `Data!A2:F` and the search keys `A1:F1` in the search box sheet, try this:

```
=iferror( 
  filter( 
    Data!A2:F, 
    not( 
      mmult( 
        sign(not(iferror(search(A1:F1, Data!A2:F), A1:F1 = ""))), 
        transpose(sign(column(A1:F1))) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ), 
  "(no matching data)" 
)
```